# Emacs installation does not initialise after updating packages

Tags: init-file, package

What should I do? After just updating packages my *Emacs* installation does not initialise. I tried the same process in two Macs with the same result. The error message (using `--debug-init`) is:

```
 Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable left)
  powerline-reset()
  require(powerline)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-583073> nil "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-misc.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2361
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-misc.el" "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-misc.el" nil nil)
  load("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-misc.el" nil nil t)
  load-file("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-misc.el")
  org-babel-load-file("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-misc.org")
  starter-kit-load("starter-kit-misc.org")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-903092> nil "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3819
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" nil nil)
  load("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" nil nil t)
  load-file("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el")
  org-babel-load-file("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.org")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2725
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262�    \306=\203�\307\310Q\202;�   \311=\204�\307\312Q\202;�\313\307\314\315#\203*�\316\202;�\313\307\314\317#\203:�\320\nB\321\202;�\316\322\323\322\211#\210\322=\203a�\324\325\326\307\327Q!\"\323\322\211#\210\322=\203`�\210\203\243�\330!\331\232\203\243�\332!\211\333P\334!\203}�\211\202\210�\334!\203\207�\202\210�\314\262\203\241�\335\"\203\237�\336\337#\210\340\341!\210\266\f?\205\260�\314\323\342\322\211#)\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" (initialization "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'") "~/_emacs" t load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7 "\n\n(fn)"]()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Comment: Have you tried updating all of your packages again from, say `emacs -Q`?

Comment: This seems to be a known [bug](https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline/issues/79)

Comment: I usually build my emacs from sources, that usually ensures I can use the latest packages.  If on Linux, you can use this guide to build it: https://coffeeorientedprogramming.wordpress.com/2015/03/11/how-to-compilebuild-emacs-from-scratch-on-fedora/

Answer (score 1):

Well generally speaking, updating software (any software) might break things if the newer version has bugs or other incompatibilities.

If a new version of something isn't working, and you don't want to go through the process of reporting a bug (or debugging it yourself), then you should simply revert back to the working version and maybe try again sometime in the future.

If you're just updating for the sake of updating, you should probably expect this sort of thing to happen from time to time.

Note that if you're using MELPA as a package repository, you should treat those packages as (potentially) unstable code.

Personally I recommend keeping your .emacs.d directory under version control, as it makes reverting any and all changes trivial.

Failing that, it looks like Emacs asks<sup>1</sup> whether you want to delete the old package after installing an update. Obviously you should be answering "no" if you don't yet know whether the new one works, as it's then simple to delete the new package directory in order to restore the older one.

<sup>1</sup> on the dev version I'm running, at least.